# select where a couple of values are in subselect

Tags: sqlite, group-by

I have a table with a primary key consisting of three fields:

```
IdPro, IdPri, IsComp
```

Actually I have some malformed situations where I have for example:

```
   IDPro IDPri  IsComp
    1      1     null
    1      1      0
```

I want to delete the rows where `IsComp = null` but ONLY if there is a correspondent doubled row.

I need to know if there is something like:

```
Delete from mytable where IsComp is null 
       AND Tuple(IDpro, IDPri) in 
           (SELECT Tuple(IDPro, IDPri) 
            FROM mytable group by IDPro, IDPri 
            HAVING Count(*) > 1 
           )
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a fake unique key for your table by concatenating `IDpro` and `IDPri`:

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE IsComp IS null AND 
      IDpro || ';' || IDPri IN (
         SELECT IDpro || ';' || IDPri 
         FROM mytable
         GROUP BY IDpro , IDPri 
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      )
```

Comment: Yep it works since fields are numerics and there are no chances to have the ';' into selected fields, thank you!